# change the hover style to clickable

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover, dock

i've been using this awesome plugin from ***janko***

> http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/06/01/Advanced-docking-using-jQuery.aspx

the only problem is, i don't want the **hover style**, how to make it as a **clickable tab** rather than **hovering tab**? please help me, thank you...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you view the live example (http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/examples/AdvancedDocking/) you will see this line of code:

```
$("#dock li").hover(function(){
            $(this).find("ul").animate({left:"40px"}, 200);
        }, function(){
            $(this).find("ul.free").animate({left:"-180px"}, 200);
       });
```

Change it to this:

```
$("#dock li").click(function(){
    if($(this).find("ul").css("left") != "40px")    {
    $(this).find("ul").animate({left:"40px"}, 200);
}
else
{
    $(this).find("ul").animate({left:"-180px"}, 200);
}
});
```

Change hover to click (or use toggle). You will also need to change some css:

Delete:

```
#dock > li:hover ul {display:block;}
```

Change display:none to display:block

```
#dock > li ul {position:absolute; top:0px; left:-180px;  z-index:-1;width:180px; display:block;
                   background-color:#F1F1F1; border:solid 1px #969696; padding:0px; margin:0px; list-style:none;}
```

Comment: i dont think you can use double function in a click can you?

Comment: instead of click you could also use toggle

Comment: @user645607 You are right. I updated the answer. It worked before, but the second function technically didn't do anything.

Comment: okay. and yeah it did, i think the second function made the slide menu slide back off the screen.

Comment: Yes it does with the hover, but not with the click.

Comment: the toggle function is worked, but i want the panel left open after i click it and close after i click it again

Answer (score 1):

you would have to change the "hover" to toggle and it would work

```
$("#dock li").toggle(
    function()
    {
        $(this).find("ul")
               .animate({left:"40px"}, 200);
    }, 
    function()
    {
        $(this).find("ul.free")
               .animate({left:"-180px"}, 200);
    });
```

Comment: how to make the panel stayed open until i click it again?

Comment: this should make it stay open until it is clicked again

Comment: no, when i move the mouse to other area of the page it close itslef

Comment: hmm.. okay instead oh toggle rename it to slideToggle

Comment: all of the tab disappear after i rename it to slideToggle

Comment: okay lol use Aaron Ray's updated answer it should definitely work